# node.js mac address filter

Tags: node.js, mac-address

Is there any **node.js module** which can do **mac address filtering**. Basically I want to put a filter based on destination mac address to implement a kind of L2 load balancer in a specific scenario. 
Though I can do the same job with combination of **iptables** and **ebtables** on Linux but still was looking if any node based solution exist for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think node.js api is so low level to do this without any module written in C. I quickly searched http://search.npmjs.org, but could not find any module to do this. Thus I think you are out of luck!